# Xna model mesh part

Tags: model, 3d, xna, mesh

So, I'm kinda new to Xna development and after reading about the handling of 3d model, I've got a doubt. I know that when we have a model, that model can have multiple meshes and each mesh multiple parts, but I don't really get such division, it seems to me like an overkill. In particular, I don't get the diffence between mesh and part and what is the latter for. I know that such a basic topic but could you clearify that to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Model` is an arbitrary collection of independent objects.

A `Mesh` is one of the aforementioned objects inside of a `Model`.  Each `Mesh` can be transformed and drawn independently of any others within the same model.

A `MeshPart` contains all of the information required to draw one piece of a `Mesh`.  A mesh can have multiple parts because some of those parts may have different rendering parameters:  for example, they may use different shaders or textures.

Consider a model representing a windmill.  It has two separate meshes:  one representing the windmill's tower, and another representing the windmill's sails.  The tower has a single part, but the sails have two:  one part, consisting of the wooden frame and drawn using `BasicEffect`; and another part, consisting of the sailcloth, which uses a special vertex shader to make the fabric flutter in the wind.

Does that make sense?